# How to add to an array from a separate view controller

Tags: ios, arrays, cocoa-touch

I have an array `players` in a view controller  `SearchViewController`, and I also have a multitude of other view controllers, which have text fields such as: `textFieldOne`and `textFieldTwo`.

How can I insert the text in `textFieldOne` to the `players` array from a view controller other than `SearchViewController` ?

Comment: Do other view controllers have a reference to the `SearchViewController` instance?

Comment: @BrianNickel how would I go about referencing it?

Answer (score 2):

You're violating the MVC design pattern by having the players array in SearchViewController, and you can see how this complicates your life.  If you followed the pattern, you'd have your players array in a separate model class.  You should create an instance of this class then pass it around to the various view controllers that need to interact with it.  If you use Key-Value Observing (KVO) on the model properties, all your view controllers can be notified when one of them changes it.  So if view controller A adds a new player, view controller B could update its table view list of player names, for instance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, sorry I'm new to object oriented programming. Thanks for your advice, I'll try to read into your suggestion.

Comment: Read up on MVC (model/view/controller) and KVO. You're going to have to learn these things or your life in iOS will be difficult.

Comment: Thanks, I will do. It seems that this is a lot more complicated to code than I would've thought.

Comment: @user2412643 It is only complicated because you must change your design patter to match the MVC paradigm. Once your app is following the MVC design pattern, your problem is fairly simple to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method to do this is using, NSNotification with userInfo.

Add the **observer** in the *view controller*, where the updates need to be made.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateArray:) name:@"updateArray" object:nil];
```

Write the method,

```
-(void)updateArray:(NSNotification*)notif
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"updateArray" object:nil];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [notif userInfo];
    [self.arrPlayers addObject:dictionary];
}
```

And then, post notification wherever, the updates need to be called from ->

```
    NSString *notificationName = @"updateArray";
    NSString *key = txtField.text;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:orientation forKey:key];
    
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notificationName object:nil userInfo:dictionary];
```

TRY IT !!

Comment: This will work but it's not ideal because it doesn't promote separation of model and controller, and it tightly couples the two unrelated view controllers.

Comment: To communicate between two different ViewControllers, that may or may not connected to each other, what other solution do u suggest other than the use of NSNotification or Delegate methods..?

Comment: Generally it's not the view controllers that are connected to each other, but rather that they are both connected to data. eg: one view controller for adding a contact, one vc for showing it. If you separate the model properly then both view controllers can observe it and respond to changes. Read up on Key Value Observing (KVO), this is a great Apple feature.